# No picture of items inside my share wishlist email MAGENTO 2

Tags: magento2

this is the code of my email template (share wish list) and it doesn't display image can someone help me with this problem?

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{trans "%customer_name wants to share this Wish List from %store_name with you:" customer_name=$customerName store_name=$store.frontend_name}}

{{depend message}}

#### {{trans "Message from %customer_name:" customer_name=$customerName}}

{{var message|raw}}
        
    


{{/depend}}

{{var items|raw}}

{{trans "View all Wish List items"}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

Comment: whats the URL of your store?

Comment: http://messmer.inntact.ch/